# Reset root account password of a CentOS 6.9 vm on azure?

Tags: azure, centos, passwords, root, azure-virtual-machine

I have a CentOS 6.9 vm on azure, it was created from a vhd disk that was uploaded.
The root account has been blocked because of failed login attemps.
So i wonder if there is a way to reset the root account password?

I've tried the steps of this post:
https://serverfault.com/questions/680460/how-to-reset-root-password-on-a-linux-vm-on-windows-azure?newreg=5d2142cb59ba400a9def39ad7245fc74

But the Azure Cli stucks at 
Installing extension "VMAccessForLinux", VM: "API-GW"

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the Azure portal, select the VM, one the left hand menu under "support + troubleshooting" is an option to reset password, ssh key, or to create a new user with sudo access.

Answer (score 0):

As I see, you create the Azure VM from a vhd disk which you uploaded. So there is a point if you install the agent in the vhd disk when you create the vhd disk, this is what you should check. If not, you could not interact with the Azure VM.

If you install the agent, there are serial ways to reset the password for your account following the document [Manage administrative users, SSH, and check or repair disks on Linux VMs using the VMAccess Extension with the Azure CLI 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/vmaccess).

You also can reset the password in Azure Portal. In the VM dashboard, you can find the **Reset password** in left, just like the screenshot below:
[image]

Comment: When i run a VMAccess Extension command i get this:
 Installing extension "VMAccessForLinux"
And it just stays there indefinetly. I've tried from the "Reset password" option in the dashboard but it won't accept "root" as username.

Comment: @JoséCousiño Yeah, you can set the user an admin user so that the user can act as the root. Or you can connect firstly and change the root in the VM.

Comment: Xu i've also tried that and it fails with a generic error message. Do you think that the only way that i have is downloading the disk and changing the shadow file from another vm?

Comment: @JoséCousiño Azure interact with the VM via the agent. If the agent in your vm is damaged and cannot communicate with Azure. What you can do is just attach the disk to other vm as a data disk and change the shadow file.

Comment: @JoséCousiño If the answer is helpful or needs more help, please let me know.